# TS Namespaces - 'is not a function' in browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser

I am learning typescript, and have tried separating my code into different files.

I have a main file structured like this:

```
// calculator.ts
namespace Calculator {
  console.log(Calculator.operate(1,2,"+"))
}
```

I have a second file with the operate function in it:

```
// Operators.ts
namespace Calculator {
  //..
  export function operate(
    a: number,
    b: number,
    operator: Operators
  ): number {
    let answer: number = 0;
    if (operator === "+") {
      answer = add(a, b);
    }
    if (operator === "-") {
      answer = subtract(a, b);
    }
    if (operator === "*") {
      answer = multiply(a, b);
    }
    if (operator === "/") {
      answer = divide(a, b);
    }
    return answer;
  }
}
```

I am running my code in my browser with a html file, using the script tag `<script src="../dist/calculator.js"></script>`

When I run the code, I get a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Calculator.operate is not a function`

How would I go around solving this?

Answer (score 0):

This documentation can help you : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#splitting-across-files

Did you use the reference tag in the calculator file ? As they say in the documentation :

*Here, we’ll split our Validation namespace across many files. Even though the files are separate, they can each contribute to the same namespace and can be consumed as if they were all defined in one place. Because there are dependencies between files, we’ll add reference tags to tell the compiler about the relationships between the files. Our test code is otherwise unchanged.*